# SSRS 2012 - Hide Duplicate Rows

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have tried these 2 methods separately  ,

1. Row Visibility

   `=IIf(Previous(Fields!name.Value) = Fields!name.Value, True, False)`

For Above , do i need to add every field?

2. HideDuplicates in Row Properties, that works, but it leaves behind blank rows.

My 2 Questions.

For 1., do i need to add every field?

For 2.,Im lost on how to remove the blank rows?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****************SOLVED******

To Solve this i used Group Properties.
Group Properties> General> Group Expression> Group On: [createon]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Filter on the table properties so that blank rows are not in the data set.

Comment: I have used Hide Duplicates, then in the filter i have added, `=IsNothing(Fields!name.Value)`, type Boolean,equal to false. It still shows the blank rows,